# Mac terminal flake8 --version can't find flake8 after pip3 download

Tags: python-3.x, sublimetext3, flake8

First of all, thank you for such a vibrant helpful community.  It is helpful! I am on OSX 10.13.  I have Python 3 and 2 installed on the mac and used the command (python3 -m pip install flake8) to download flake8.  All seemed to go smoothly, but when I then type:

$ flake8 --version

It says "Command not found".  I want to use flake8 in sublime text 3 but right now, it doesn't seem to be pointing to the correct location.  If I type:

$ pip3 show -f flake8

It finds the location (code below).  Any help would be appreciated.

---

```
Name: flake8
Version: 3.7.7
Summary: the modular source code checker: pep8, pyflakes and co
Home-page: https://gitlab.com/pycqa/flake8
Author: Tarek Ziade
Author-email: tarek@ziade.org
License: MIT
Location: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages
Requires: entrypoints, pycodestyle, pyflakes, mccabe
Required-by: 
Files:
  ../../../bin/flake8
  flake8-3.7.7.dist-info/INSTALLER
  flake8-3.7.7.dist-info/LICENSE
  flake8-3.7.7.dist-info/METADATA
  flake8-3.7.7.dist-info/RECORD
  flake8-3.7.7.dist-info/WHEEL
  flake8-3.7.7.dist-info/entry_points.txt
  flake8-3.7.7.dist-info/top_level.txt
  flake8/__init__.py
  flake8/__main__.py
  flake8/__pycache__/__init__.cpython-37.pyc
  flake8/__pycache__/__main__.cpython-37.pyc
  flake8/__pycache__/checker.cpython-37.pyc
  flake8/__pycache__/defaults.cpython-37.pyc
  flake8/__pycache__/exceptions.cpython-37.pyc
  flake8/__pycache__/processor.cpython-37.pyc
  flake8/__pycache__/statistics.cpython-37.pyc
  flake8/__pycache__/style_guide.cpython-37.pyc
  flake8/__pycache__/utils.cpython-37.pyc
  flake8/api/__init__.py
  flake8/api/__pycache__/__init__.cpython-37.pyc
  flake8/api/__pycache__/legacy.cpython-37.pyc
  flake8/api/legacy.py
  flake8/checker.py
  flake8/defaults.py
  flake8/exceptions.py
  flake8/formatting/__init__.py
  flake8/formatting/__pycache__/__init__.cpython-37.pyc
  flake8/formatting/__pycache__/base.cpython-37.pyc
  flake8/formatting/__pycache__/default.cpython-37.pyc
  flake8/formatting/base.py
  flake8/formatting/default.py
  flake8/main/__init__.py
  flake8/main/__pycache__/__init__.cpython-37.pyc
  flake8/main/__pycache__/application.cpython-37.pyc
  flake8/main/__pycache__/cli.cpython-37.pyc
  flake8/main/__pycache__/debug.cpython-37.pyc
  flake8/main/__pycache__/git.cpython-37.pyc
  flake8/main/__pycache__/mercurial.cpython-37.pyc
  flake8/main/__pycache__/options.cpython-37.pyc
  flake8/main/__pycache__/setuptools_command.cpython-37.pyc
  flake8/main/__pycache__/vcs.cpython-37.pyc
  flake8/main/application.py
  flake8/main/cli.py
  flake8/main/debug.py
  flake8/main/git.py
  flake8/main/mercurial.py
  flake8/main/options.py
  flake8/main/setuptools_command.py
  flake8/main/vcs.py
  flake8/options/__init__.py
  flake8/options/__pycache__/__init__.cpython-37.pyc
  flake8/options/__pycache__/aggregator.cpython-37.pyc
  flake8/options/__pycache__/config.cpython-37.pyc
  flake8/options/__pycache__/manager.cpython-37.pyc
  flake8/options/aggregator.py
  flake8/options/config.py
  flake8/options/manager.py
  flake8/plugins/__init__.py
  flake8/plugins/__pycache__/__init__.cpython-37.pyc
  flake8/plugins/__pycache__/manager.cpython-37.pyc
  flake8/plugins/__pycache__/pyflakes.cpython-37.pyc
  flake8/plugins/manager.py
  flake8/plugins/pyflakes.py
  flake8/processor.py
  flake8/statistics.py
  flake8/style_guide.py
  flake8/utils.py
```

---

I believe the output of the code is asking me for some more dependencies but not sure what.  Thank you.

Comment: Try the suggestion here: http://flake8.pycqa.org/en/latest/user/invocation.html
There might be a variety of reasons why it's not working. It's either a version problem, or that something went wrong in the path.
`python<version> -m flake8`

Comment: Thank you for the response.  I am reading this now.  It sort of is making sense.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [zsh: command not found: flake8 but flake8 is installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45956359/zsh-command-not-found-flake8-but-flake8-is-installed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that flake8 might not be in $PATH environment variable. Try `which flake8` to be sure. If it's not present, make sure to add it.

For e.g in my work environment

```
$ which flake8
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/flake8
```

and in my .bash_profile which I use to declare PATH environment variable

```
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin:/usr/local/bin:...."
export $PATH
```

Comment: Thank you for the response.  In typing ```which flake8``` there is nothing returned.  So that being the case, how would I add it?  Adding to this, the linter in SublimeText 3 is saying **SublimeLinter: WARNING: cannot locate 'flake8'. Fill in the 'python' or 'executable' setting.**

Comment: I have run `python3.7 -m flake8` and it spits out a giant amount of output.

`$ python3.7 -m flake8
./.virtualenvs/myvenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/retrying.py:1:1: E266 too many leading '#' for block comment
./.virtualenvs/myvenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/retrying.py:3:1: E266 too many leading '#' for block comment
......many more lines
`

Comment: Thank you, Devesh.  Just so I make sure I understand.  When I use the `which flake8` command, nothing happens.  However, I can see that flake 8 is **/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/flake8**  

How do I add this to my .bash_profile?  I understand using nano on it. 
 Would my addition look like `PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin:/usr/local/bin/flak8"
export $PATH`  Thank you so much!  I really appreciate it.

Comment: Yes that is correct, then you can run ```source ~/.bash_profile``` to persist your env var and you can then use flake8 in terminal

Comment: Great, please accept the answer if it helped you solve the problem

Comment: Hi Devesh, but it didn't seem to do anything when I upvoted the answer.  Want to make sure you get the credit.